# RegEx - How to select all text in between backes (multiline)

Tags: sql, regex, string, multiline

Basically, what i want to do is to parse a `*.sql` file and select all `CREATE TABLE` Statements. Example below:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for aes_interval
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aes_interval`;
CREATE TABLE `aes_interval`  (
  `processcode` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `overstaying` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `floating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`processcode`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

by running a RegEx that would select all in between `(...)` i will be able to get an output/substringed text like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `aes_interval`  (
  `processcode` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `overstaying` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `floating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`processcode`) USING BTREE
)
```

i've tried `CREATE TABLE`\w+`\((.|\n)*?\)` but it only returns the output below:

```
CREATE TABLE `aes_interval`  (
  `processcode` bigint(20)
```

hopefully, i can pick up the proper regex here.

Comment: What are you using to "parse" the files? sed? grep? something else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming the `CREATE TABLE` statements are terminated by semicolon, and therefore that semicolon does not appear until the end of each statement, then the following regex should work:

```
(CREATE TABLE.*?;)
```

There is a caveat that the above would need to run in a tool/language with dot configured to match newline.  And also multiline match mode would need to be enabled.

### Demo

**Edit:**

I suspect that lazy dot is not working on Sublime Text.  If so, then you can try the following pattern:

```
(CREATE TABLE[^;]*)
```

Comment: i checked on `regex101` and verified that it works. however, it doesn't when i'm tring the regex on sublime text 3 :(

Comment: @Nil I updated my question; please try the second pattern.

Comment: it works now. thank you for your assistance. i'll try it on my module now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this `(CREATE TABLE.*?((\(.*?\)).*?)+\))` in https://regex101.com/

Comment: this also works, as per `regex101`. however, unlike the first answer (which only breaks it down to 2 matches) - your's is breaking those 2 matches into 3 sub-groups. also doesn't work with sublime text 3 upon trying tho :(